# DOM: I can't access dynamically created elements. What's wrong

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I am creating a form with AJAX. The way I have created the form is by writing out the html form elements in the innerHTML of the div where I'm putting the form

```
div.innerHTML += '&nbsp;<input type="text" name="day" id="eventDay" size="2" maxlength="2" value="'+response.day+'" />,';
div.innerHTML += '&nbsp;20<input type="text" name="year" id="eventYear" size="2" maxlength="2" value="'+response.year+'" /><br /><br />';
```

I've also tried doing this by using `document.createElement('input');` but this is giving me problems as well. Once I have the form created, when I try to submit the values using another AJAX function, I am unable to access the values of the input boxes by using `document.getElementById('eventDay').value;` for instance. I don't want to submit the form using HTTP directly, but would rather submit it with an AJAX function. I have no idea why I can't access the values of these input boxes from the other function. Please help!

Comment: What problems do you have when you use "document.createElement('input')"?

Comment: Can you see the elements in the page source after they are created?

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I would never have figured out had I not looked at the html source. I was replacing an old html form with the one created by javascript, but I hadn't gotten rid of the old html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sheepishly have to admit that I had other elements on the page with the same ids as the input boxes I was using. So, the answer to this one is that I didn't check my html well enough, and assumed the problem was with javascript. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try `div.appendChild()` instead and pass the raw html in there.

Or you can create the node (`document.createElement`) and then add the attributes to it properly through `inputvarname.setAttribute()`. After that's done, then append that node as a child to the div.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery you get created elements using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function